# Spring boot environment based configuration with docker in Pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jenkins-pipeline, devops, properties-file

I have one micro-service, that is running using a pipeline on AWS EKS cluster. So it passes through each environment. I need to update this application, so that whenever, it will pass through from different environment, it takes specific environment variables. What I thought to do this to add application.properties file for different environment builds and add the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod|dev|test, whatever required. But I am new to this pipeline stuffs and need to understand, where I will add this profile specific properties so that each time, the build runs in different environment, it take the specific environment based profile to activate it.

Comment: Here is a [blog](https://stackabuse.com/spring-boot-profiles-for-dev-and-prod-environments/) about setting spring boot profiles for different Environments you can refer to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jenkins pipeline or any other pipeline for the build, have environment variable for for each environment and during docker build it will automatically build based one environment you select

something like this

docker build --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=$environment-variable(specific env can be from pipeline parameter) .

SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=$ENVIRONMENT

Or else

You can have one file for each env and have that specific file picked during docker build